# Function for Column Cypher

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on an exercise which asks to write a function that creates a column cypher for a given message. I wanted to extend this a little further and have this column cypher apply to messages of all lengths. For those who don't know a column cypher would work like this.

Say my message is "THIS IS A TEST CYPHER". We specify that each row has a length of 5. Now, every string might not have the length needed to be exactly divisible by our specific row length so we pad the message with "X". The message would then look as such:

```
THISI
SATES
TCYPH
ERXXX
```

The message that would be sent would look like this then "TSTEHACRITYXSEPXISHX"

Here is what I have so far, first a function that preps the message for use:

```
def prep_msg(message, row_length):
    message = message.upper().replace(' ', '')
    num_xs = len(message) % row_length
    message += 'X' * (row_length - num_xs)
    return message
```

Next I wanted to create a dictionary where each column is the key, and the values are the letters associated with that column. After this step I could go about processing my message. However, I am stuck on this step as it seems the output I am getting is completely empty. My second function looks like this:

```
def column_dict(message, row_length):
    message = prep_msg(message, 3)
    num_cols = range(row_length)
    column_dict = {}
    for x in range(len(message)):
        for i in num_cols:
            if x % row_length == i:
                column_dict['column_{0}'.format(i)] = [].append(message[x])
    return column_dict
```

The message I am using is this `message = "This message is very secret"`

Here is the outputs from my function:

```
prep_msg(message, 3)
>> 'THISMESSAGEISVERYSECRETX'

column_cypher(message, 3)
>> {'column_0': None, 'column_1': None, 'column_2': None}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to why my 2nd function is not working? Thanks!

Comment: `[].append(message[x])` doesn't return anything, so assigning its result to your `column_dict` wont do anything

Comment: you probably want to do something like `column_dict['column_{0}'.format(i)] = [message[x]]`

Comment: That doesn't work because each subsequent letter overwrites the previous one for that key.

Comment: then you'll want to append to the list if it exists and create a new one if it doesn't

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: I should accept my own answer @Prune?

Comment: Sure, if that's the one you like the best.  You won't get 15 points for it, but it will help others find the best response.  If that feels weird, we *could* edit your solution as an update to mine, but that's a bit awkward in maintenance.  I'm happy with upvotes -- the long-term purpose is for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up changing the structuring of my function thanks to @Prune. Here is the way it ended up working for anyone who is interested in the future and stumbles upon this question.

```
def prep_msg(message, row_length):
    message = message.upper().replace(' ', '')
    num_xs = len(message) % row_length
    message += 'X' * (row_length - num_xs)
    return message

def encode_column(message, rows):
    prep_msg(message, row_length)
    col_list = [message[i::row_length] for i in range(row_length)]
    encoded_message = ''.join(col_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

**append** adds the argument to the given list, but the modification is *in place*.  The return value is **None**, which goes into your dictionary.  Change the statement to have a better expression on the right side, such as **[message[x]]** ... modified to accumulate the letters.

Even better, note that your dictionary is more of a list (i.e. array).  You'll likely do better by turning your basic structure into a list of strings:

```
["THISI", "SATES", "TCYPH", "ERXXX"]
```

Your indexing here will be much neater than constructing "column_{0}".
Then use simple list comprehensions to build your column-major string.

Is that enough of a hint to get you moving?

Comment: I didn't even think of list comprehension here. But yes this helped. I changed it to this `columns = [message[i::row_length] for i in range(row_length)]` and it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I was trying not to give away code -- you learn so much more if you develop it yourself.  When you have to invent new keys, you probably shouldn't use a dictionary.  When you naturally for the data into an array, use a list.